Nested ActionMenu
The nested ActionMenu example from the documentation seems not to work on a Windows machine, but works fine on MacOs. Using the code provided there, in the Windows version, there is no way to select the second level menu items (i.e. the "4!", the "7!", the "4!!" or "7!!" etc. The screenshot below illustrates the issue - compare to the one from a MacOs system.
Thank you!
Stefan



It works for me in 13.3 on Win10. Please specify your Mathematica and Windows version.

13.2 on Win11, accessed via MS RemoteDesktop

14.0 on a Linux machine does not show the issue.
